# how to validate data insert to table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using addpermission function to save values in to permission table.

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $id,  Permission $permission)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'status'   => 'required'
    ]);

    $permission = new Permission;

    $permission->status = $request->input('status');
    $permission->project_id       = $id;
    $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
    $permission->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with(
        'info',
        'Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully'
    );
}
```

this is My permiisionadd form action

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post"
    action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.permission', $project->id,$collaborator->id) }}">

    <input type="hidden" id="cid" name="cid" value="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id }}" />
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="status" class="control-label">Choose Permission</label>
    <select name="status" id="status">
    <option value="">Choose a status</option>
    <option value="3">View Only</option>
    <option value="2">Edit Tasks</option>
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    </select>
    @if ($errors->has('status'))
    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
    @endif
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

now I need to validate this form if some user add new value to the existing row (generate some message)

how can I do this?

Comment: You already have validation code, whats's the problem?

Comment: No, that validation is for empty values. that means if I click button without values it will validate. but if I add values to same user for existing it is also save with new records. I need validation for this (if I add values to existing records it should validate)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you may have to use the unique validation rule on your hidden cid field, like this:

```
     $this->validate($request, [
        'cid'      => 'unique:permissions,collaborator_id',
        'status'   => 'required'
    ]);
```

This way if this user has already a row in the table, it won't let him create a new one and a validation error will be displayed.

However may have to create a custom error message for this, to help the user understand why his form is not accepted. Also dont forget to create an extra span somewhere on your form for the errors of the `cid` field to appear:

```
@if ($errors->has('cid'))
   <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('cid') }}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: I need like your first validation. but when I used it generated following error    **syntax error, unexpected ''status'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'**

Comment: Yes, there was a comma missing after the cid rule.

Comment: but when I put comma now occurred this error **SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'samantha.permission' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `permission` where `collaborator_id` = 29)**

Comment: How is your permissions table called? Where is your Permission model store its data? Please fill the correct table name in place of `permissions` and try again.